# Контекстное меню появляется вне интерфейса окна

Tags: python, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты, qlineedit, qmenu

При нажатии **`ПКМ`** по `QLineEdit` должно высвечиваться контекстное меню на месте клика, но оно появляется вне проекта.

Как исправить? 
При необходимости могу скинуть полностью код.

---

**UPDATE**

```
from imports import *
class Ui_MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self,MainWindow):
                super().__init__()
                MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
                MainWindow.resize(260, 285)
                self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
                self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
                self.centralWidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
                self.TxtPatchFileLine = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralWidget)
                self.TxtPatchFileLine.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 10, 150, 20))
                self.TxtPatchFileLine.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
                self.TxtPatchFileLine.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.show_context_menu)
                self.TxtPatchFileLine.setObjectName("TxtPatchFileLine")
                MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        def show_context_menu(self, point):
                menu = QMenu()    
                action = menu.addAction("Hello!")
                menu.addAction(action)
                action.triggered.connect(self.triggered_action)
                menu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(point))
        def triggered_action(self, q):
                print(self.sender().text())



if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        ui = Ui_MainWindow(MainWindow)
        ui.__init__(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: как мне это сделать? Это и так минимально для вашего понимания.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример**

Задавая вопрос о проблеме, источник которой вы видите в своем коде, можно рассчитывать на получение гораздо более качественных ответов, если привести код, с помощью которого участники смогут воспроизвести проблему. Такой пример кода должен быть:

- **минимальным** — максимально сократите код, сохранив все проблемные моменты;
- **самодостаточным** — приведите все части кода, необходимые для воспроизведения проблемы;
- **воспроизводимым** — проверьте, что используя приведенный пример кода, другие участники смогут воспроизвести проблему.

... и дальше по тексту.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.lineEdit.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.lineEdit.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.show_context_menu)

        self.layout  = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget) 
        self.layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.layout.addStretch(1)

        '''
        self.TxtPatchFileLine = QtWidgets.QMenu(self)
        action = self.TxtPatchFileLine.addAction('Обзор:')
        action.triggered.connect(lambda: QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Info', 'Hello!'))
        '''
                
    def show_context_menu(self, point):
        menu = QMenu()    
        action = menu.addAction("Hello!")
        menu.addAction(action)
        action.setIcon(QIcon("D:/_Qt/img/qt-logo.png")) 
        action.triggered.connect(self.triggered_action)
        menu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(point))
#-        self.TxtPatchFileLine.exec(self.mapToGlobal(point))

    def triggered_action(self, q):
        print(self.sender().text())
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(400, 300)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

> Все равно не помогло. все также появляется вне проекта.
>
> В вашем примере `строка 29 => action = menu.addAction("Hello!")` появляется конкретно на месте клика но у меня оно появляется где-то в верхней правой части экрана При необходимости могу добавить весь код.
>
> обновил код в вопросе оставив то что нужно для лучшего понимания

Я добавил обновление в свой ответ, проверьте.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setObjectName("MainWindow")                                                 # !!! self
                
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)                                        # !!! self
        
#  --------> v                                                                             v  
        self.txtPatchFileLine = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralWidget)                  # txtPatchFileLine
        self.txtPatchFileLine.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 10, 150, 20))
        self.txtPatchFileLine.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.txtPatchFileLine.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.show_context_menu)
        self.txtPatchFileLine.setObjectName("txtPatchFileLine")
                
    def show_context_menu(self, point):
        menu = QMenu()    
        action = menu.addAction("Hello!")
        menu.addAction(action)
        action.triggered.connect(self.triggered_action)
        menu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(point))
                
    def triggered_action(self, q):
        print(self.sender().text())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ''' так делать не надо
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow(MainWindow)
    ui.__init__(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    '''
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(260, 285)
    w.show()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Все равно не помогло. все также появляется вне проекта.

Comment: @Kickwall, скопируйте и запустите мой пример  и на основании запуска моего примера, расскажите/покажите что не так.

Comment: В вашем примере 
```
строка 29 => action = menu.addAction("Hello!")
```
появляется конкретно на месте клика 
но у меня оно появляется где-то в верхней правой части экрана
При необходимости могу добавить весь код.

Comment: обновил код в вопросе оставив то что нужно для лучшего понимания

Comment: @Kickwall, Я добавил обновление в свой ответ, проверьте.